# writing bytes of fixed size one by one in image file

Tags: java, image, file, byte

I want to write a fixed size (say 1024 kb) in an image file. I know the following code works for appending bytes in a file.

```
fos=new FileOutputStream(new File("profile1.jpg"),true);//correct format
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("C:/test.jpg",true));//did not work out, wrong //code but i want to append the byte 1024 at a time.
```

Is it possible to append the byte in an image file. Please anyone help me with this.

Comment: just using fos.write(byte[]) cannot work?

Comment: I am working ina client server application.In the sender side, I am reading the  file using fileinputstream with 1024 bytes at once to ship the packet. But when i write those byte arrays to another byte array one by one,  fos.write(byte[]) fails to write the file. I could print the string of bytes in the console but could not make the file out of it using file input stream. In the case, where i do not have to copy it into another array, fos.write(byte[]) is working fine. the problem is, when i write the bytes one by one.